# MongoDB Aggregation add value based on document in same collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, time-series, aggregation

I have a problem with MongoDB aggregation pipeline that I can't seem to be able to solve.

I have the following document here ->

`{
    name: 'name',
    values: [
     { value: 12, date: 2019-01-01 },
     { value: 26, date: 2019-01-02 },
     { value: 34, date: 2019-01-03 }
    ]
   }`

I have an aggregation pipeline running, and I want to output the following document with $project ->

`{
    name: 'name',
    values: [
     { value: 12, date: 2019-01-01, changeDay: 0 },
     { value: 26, date: 2019-01-02, changeDay: 14 },
     { value: 34, date: 2019-01-03, changeDay: 8 }
    ]
   }`

That is I need the changeDay to be a subtraction of value from a document minus the value from a document before that one, and so on.

I hope I made myself clear enough.

If it helps - I'm trying to query a simple time-series document by a time range, and I need to output the change of a value of every day.

So far I have this MongoDB aggregation ->

```
`[
  {
    '$match': {
      'pageid': '36606016799'
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'likes', 
      'localField': 'likes', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'likes'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$likes'
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'likes.date': {
        '$gte': Date('Sat, 29 Dec 2018 22:00:00 GMT'), 
        '$lte': Date('Tue, 01 Jan 2019 22:05:00 GMT')
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$name', 
      'likes': {
        '$push': '$likes'
      }, 
      'picture': {
        '$first': '$$ROOT.picture'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      '_id': 1, 
      'picture': 1, 
      'likes': {
        'value': 1, 
        'change': {
          '$map': {
            'input': '$likes', 
            'as': 'like', 
            'in': {
              '$add': [
                '$$like.value', 100
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]`
```

You can see I tried a $map in the last $project stage, but that doesn't work here... I don't know how can I select an item before the one where the cursor currently is, to reach its value and to subtract...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560777/mongodb-aggregation-query-to-subtract-and-grouping-of-cumulative-value/43594156#43594156 Have a look .. might help you..

Comment: This one as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52426914/query-to-get-a-value-by-subtracting-a-value-from-current-and-next-document/52430679#52430679

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it is even possible with the aggregation pipeline.
But if does, its not worth to make the aggregation so complex.
Fetch the data and then perform the business logic on the server side.

Comment: I guess You're right, I'm closing this up and will perform the change logic in front-end with JS. :) Thanks for Your input guys.